# checkmarx Client_Reflected_File_Download

Tags: ajax, jsonp, checkmarx, secure-coding

Checkmarx has detected a security vulnerability in the code: *Cross-domain `jsonp` ajax call not `XSS` safe*. The suggestion given as: An explicit file name is not defined for the **Content-Disposition** header. Filename attribute is required in order to prevent the browser from assuming the resource is an executable and download a possibly malicious file."

The code works fine but security tool has identified this.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "https://www.example.com?format=rich&client=aem_frontend",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 data: "&q=" + request.term,
 success: function(data) {
  $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'none');
  if (data.results.length > 0) {
   response($.map(data.results, function(item) {
    return {
     label: item.name
    }
   }));
  } else {
   $('.ui-autocomplete ').css('display', 'none');
   $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'block');
   $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'block');
   // $('#zero-result').removeClass("noDisplay").css('display','block');
   //$('#err_text').text("Whoops! We couldn’t find any matches for "+request.term);
  }

 },
 error: function(data) {
  alert("inside failure" + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
 }
});
```

How to fix this vulnerability?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You appear to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: I think Cx just inform you that your AJAX request is not XSS Safe only. After checking the query in the CX query, this rely to a medium trheat in TypeScript category and CWE-425. IMHO problem seems to be in the line with que request.term that can force you browse to a URL you don't trust. Try to elimintate this kind of code and submti it back to your scanner

Answer (score -1):

In Jquery Ajax request you can define header in it for example given below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com?format=rich&client=aem_frontend",



    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },



    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: "&q=" + request.term,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'none');
        if (data.results.length > 0) {
            response($.map(data.results, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name
                }
            }));
        }
        else {
            $('.ui-autocomplete ').css('display', 'none');
            $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'block');
            $('.searchPanel').css('display', 'block');
            // $('#zero-result').removeClass("noDisplay").css('display','block');
            //$('#err_text').text("Whoops! We couldn’t find any matches for "+request.term);
        }

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("inside failure" + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
    }
});
```